# Sql query optimization to fetch faster results

Tags: mysql, optimization

This query is taking quite a lot of time to execute. How do I optimize it?

```
SELECT user, count(tweet) FROM tweet WHERE 1 = 1 GROUP BY user
```

My database has a structure like this:

```
DATE | USER | TWEET | ID
```

I want need a query to find number of tweets by each user. The size of MYSQL database is around 3 GB.

Comment: Index by user will help

Comment: this is the TWEET table structure not the database table ?

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
select user, count(tweet)
from tweet
where 1 = 1
group by user;
```

Unfortunately, MySQL can be bad at optimizations for `group by`.  You can try adding an index `tweet(user)` and changing the `count(tweet)` to `count(*)`.  Another possibility is to use that index and do:

```
select u.user, (select count*) from tweet t where t.user = u.user)
from user u;
```

Sometimes, doing the aggregation in a subquery can help, because MySQL makes better use of indexes with correlated subqueries.

Finally, if you need this information readily available for *all* users at the same time, then you might need a trigger.  If you only need it for one user at a time, then the above index will be very beneficial.